# Systemd service with executable running via wrapper fails to notify watchdog

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm working with a systemd service file that runs a binary executable as "notify" type service. The executable is using C language API `sd_notify` function to send "pings" to the systemd watchdog. Now, however, I need to wrap the executable with a bash script.

The isssue I'm having though is that the watchdog pings are rejected, because systemd only accepts them from a "main pid" which belongs to the wrapper script, not to the wrapped binary. Is there any way to let systemd know that is should accept those pings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your wrapper script `exec` the main binary instead of starting it as a child. The script will be replaced by the main executable, retaining the same PID.

(If the script needs to do something *after* the binary exits – that should go in systemd's `ExecStartPost=` or `ExecStopPost=` instead.)

There are alternatives including `NotifyAccess=` to allow notify-socket access to all processes within the cgroup, but they mostly work around the real issue of the "main PID" not tracking the correct process.